# How to set grease pencil general default properties across scenes

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm working as a storyboard artist on a project, with Blender, more specifically Grease Pencil. As I'm trying to optimize the workflow and remove regular, unnecessary step, I wish to set defaults value to my tools, which are basically : a specific brush, and a specific vertex color, as well as a specific eraser parameter.

When I set all of this up in a default scene, it works fine if I create a new GP Object : the correct brush, color and eraser are on. But, if I create a new scene within the same file, it's all reset. Back to the default pencil brush, back to the green vertex color (but inactive as it sets material color as default), and overall, my "default settings" are bypassed.

In the scenes I'm supposed to work with, this quickly become nightmare-ish. Every shot is a different blender scene within a file, and for every shot, I have to yet again, for the same GP object that was already painted on in another scene, pick a brush, pick a color, etc. I've looked everywhere online, I can not figure out how to set an actual default brush other than the pencil, another color, etc.

This is quite upsetting as it is an immense waste of time. Has anyone figured this out, and are there solutions?

Thank you very much

Comment: Set the tools to the parameters you want. Then save the project as default File>Save Startup File.

Comment: thank you for answering, but as I said, this is what I did but it doesn't work. I set the parameters, it works for the default scene but if I create another one (within the same file) the parameters reset, and if I open another scene and create a new grease pencil object, same thing, "my" default parameters don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

MTKay,

I am just going to make a suggestion,

But have you tried to make a full copy of the Scene.

Scene > New

[image]

Scene > New > Full Copy

[image]

I would certainly learn about the concept of linking and appending Libraries. I believe these might be the missing piece to your adventure with Blender.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/index.html

I think after you make it over this issue....your time will much more fun!!

Happy Blendering!

We all learn by sharing what we know!
Smartdog

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for answering. Unfortunately, the files I currently have to work with are already completely set up, hence why I was hoping for default settings. In the future, when I have to set up the files myself, I will indeed make proper copies.